# Textarea maxlength IE issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have this code which works perfect on all browser but It is not working on IE.
Not sure the reason. does anybody have any idea please?
Here is the demo on [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmkw3/)

```
<textarea name="detail" class="words"></textarea>

$(words).keyup(function() {

            var maxWords = 24;
            var a = words.val().split(' ');
            var word=0, i=0;
            for(; (i<a.length) && (word<maxWords); ++i)
            if(a[i].length) ++word;
            maxL = a.splice(0,i).join(' ');

            var wordsLimit = words.val().split(" ").length;
            var charLimit = $.trim($(".words"));
            maxLength = maxL.replace(/\s/g, '');

            if(wordsLimit > 25) {
                $(this).next('span').remove();
                $(this).after('<span class="error">*Max word limit 25</span>');
                $(this).attr('maxlength',maxL.length)
            } else {
                $(this).removeAttr('maxlength') 
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you state what version of IE? and what versions have you tested it on? have you tested it in other browsers (of the same age as your IE version?)

Comment: Any chance you can define what you mean by it doesn't work? and tell us what you expect it to do?

Comment: I have set max character length as fit in 25 words. Other browser won't let you to type more than 25 words but IE doesn't detech it.
Its happening below IE9

Comment: No I can't see any error

Comment: here is the demo on jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmkw3/)

Comment: IE doesn't support the maxlength attribute on textareas.

Answer (score 1):

From Kevin B's: http://jsfiddle.net/5Zd3V/9/

```
$(words).keypress(function(e) {
    var maxWords = 4,
        wordLimit = words.val().match(/\S+/g),
        isNoneWhite = String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/\s/i),
        limitReached = wordLimit ? wordLimit.length >= maxWords && isNoneWhite : false;

    words.next('span.error').text(
        limitReached ? '*Max word limit ' + maxWords : ''
    );

    return !limitReached;
});​
```

Think the only thing you guys were missing is making sure the character being typed does NOT create a new word (isNonWhite)

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support the maxlength attribute on textareas.

Try this(*updated*):

```
words.keypress(function(e) {
    var maxWords = 4;
    var wordCount = words.val().match(/\S+/g);
    wordCount = wordCount ? wordCount.length : 0;
    if (wordCount > maxWords && e.which != 8) {
        words.next('span').remove();
        words.after('<span class="error">*Max word limit ' + maxWords + '</span>');
        return false;
    }
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5Zd3V/8/

Comment: It is working but you can't edit the text any more. Any suggestion

Comment: The logic here is flawed, you can enter as many words as you want as long as they are on different lines.

Comment: I think that is about as close as it's going to get. you can't simply remove the last character because it may not be the last character that was entered.